# Error when trying to save with user defaults

Tags: ios, swift

Im having issues saving the table view data to user defaults, im getting the error " Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type '[ViewController.ItemRow]' " in the load function. It gives the error at the line "items = loadedData". Does anyone know why its giving me this error!I dont know if im even doing it right.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var OrderNumberLabel: RoundedLabel2!
    @IBOutlet weak var CostLabel: RoundedLabel2!
    @IBOutlet weak var ProfitLabel: RoundedLabel2!
    @IBOutlet weak var TotalLabel: RoundedLabel2!

    @IBOutlet weak var itemTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var saleTextField: UITextField!

        var items: [ItemRow] = []

        struct ItemRow
        {
          var first: String
          var second: String
          var third: String
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            load()
//            tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        }


    func save(){
        UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "saved")

    }

    func load(){
        if let loadedData:[String] = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "saved") as? [String]{
            items = loadedData
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        insertNewItems()
        save()
//        profit()
//
    }

//    func profit(){
//        let priceValue = Double(priceTextField.text!)
//        let saleValue = Double(saleTextField.text!)
//
//        if priceValue != nil && saleValue != nil {
//
//            let outputValue = Double (priceValue! - saleValue!)
//
//            ProfitLabel.text = "\(outputValue)"
//            }
//    }


        func insertNewItems() {


            let newVideoRow = ItemRow(first: itemTextField.text!, second: priceTextField.text!, third: saleTextField.text!)
            items.append(newVideoRow)



            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 0)

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()


            itemTextField.text = ""
            priceTextField.text = ""
            saleTextField.text = ""

            view.endEditing(true)
        }

    }





    extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate{

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return items.count
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

             let ItemTitle = items[indexPath.row]

               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell") as! ItemCell
               cell.itemLabel.text = ItemTitle.first
               cell.priceLabel.text = ItemTitle.second
               cell.saleLabel.text = ItemTitle.third
               return cell
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            return true
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            if editingStyle == .delete {
                items.remove(at: indexPath.row)

                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()
                save()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You saved item as `struct`, not `string`.

Comment: `items` is an `[ItemRow]`, not a `[String]`

Comment: it has to be a struct so how do i fix

Comment: may be you have to get data as [ItemRow] not as [String]  in loadedData

Answer (score 0):

Make your struct conform to the `Codable` protocol. This is as simple as changing one line to:-

```
struct ItemRow : Codable
```

Your `save` function can be:-

```
if let data = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(items) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "SavedItems")
}
```

And `load` can be:

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let data = defaults.data(forKey: "SavedItems") {
        items = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([ItemRow].self, from: data)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

A quick look around SO the opinion seems to be that this shouldn't be used for large data sets. So this will get you started, but it may be worth considering a solution a bit more 'database-y' if you need larger amounts of data (e.g. CoreData or Realm).

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value on line "tableView.reloadData()" in load function

Comment: Have you linked your `tableView` to the table view in your view controller (since you're not subclassing a UITableViewController)? Check the outlet is connected to the table view in Storyboard.

Comment: yeah its linked

Comment: If the error you state is occurring on the line you state, no it isn't. Try removing and relinking with Ctrl-Drag. `tableView` is the only optional var on the line `tableView.reloadData`.

Comment: i mean i just unlinked and re-linked it and still comes up with that error

Comment: is it from me calling the load() function in view did load

Comment: Is `load` called from elsewhere - from another VC prior to `viewDidLoad()` for instance? I can't see any other way that would be null if the linking is correct. Calling from `viewDidLoad` is fine since the UITableView should be created and linked by then.

Comment: when i just delete the line "tableView.reloadData()", it works and still saves it which is weird

Comment: Hmm. Actually I can't see where you're setting the `tableView.dataSource = self` so I think something else is going on if your table shows the correct data.

Comment: do i need to add tableView.dataSource = self somehwere?

Comment: Yes somewhere, in `viewDidLoad()` is the usual place - this will probably give you the same 'Unexpectedly found nil...' error.

Comment: ya same errrorr

Comment: Then the outlet is definitely not linked correctly. Not sure I can help much without seeing it - sorry.

Comment: Ideas - check your storyboard VC has the correct class selected for it; check the Assistant shows the correct class for the Storyboard table view and appears under Automatic..

Comment: it doesnt let me put a class for the table view

Comment: Not for the table, for the View Controller (should be set to ViewController, as in your class).